# How to check with TSQL if I'm connected to an Azure Managed Instance in a Failover Group?

Tags: sql-server, failover, azure-sql-managed-instance

How can I check with TSQL if I am connected to an Azure Managed Instance that's in a Failover Group?

For Always-On we can use this:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled')
```

But in the case of Azure Managed Instances in a Failover Group, that returns 0.

It's easy to check if I'm connected to a secondary, because the databases will be read-only. But if I'm connected to the primary, how can I tell?

I also tried:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered')
```

Which returns 1 for standalone servers, and seems to returns null for all Azure Managed Instances (regardless of if it's in a failover group or not) and all Azure SQL databases.

Comment: Yeah that's my workaround at the moment, -- the obvious downside is that someone needs to maintain that table going forward -- very likely to get forgotten over time.

Comment: Sure, though how often are you adding / removing Azure Managed Instances, heh?

Comment: But that's the problem -- almost never, so my colleagues would very quickly forget to update the table, because they never touch it.

Comment: Idk, for something that *might* happen once every *insert long time period* doesn't sound like a big issue, even if forgotten once. But anything's possible I guess. Proper documentation should help ensure it's a non-issue too. But I understand none of this exactly answers your question. I'm not familiar enough with Managed Instances, but I wouldn't doubt their might not be a proper field to determine what you're trying to figure out.